# Ajax Modal Opens in Chrome But Doesn't Open in IE and FireFox

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

The following Kendo Modal opens in chrome but doesn't work in IE and FireFox.
Go to https://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net/spa1/#/invoice
Then click the "New Client" button.

Code to open Ajax Modal is as follows:

```
function KendoWin(win, btn, url, width, height, callbackfn) {



                $("#" + btn).unbind("click"); //remove previous event

                    url = win.location.href.split('#')[0] + url;
                    //alert(url);

                   var window = $("<div id='window' style='margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;'/>"), 
                    btnNewClient = $("#" + btn)
                                .bind("click", function() {

                                      window.kendoWindow({
                                                actions: ["Maximize", "Minimize", "Close"], 
                                                modal: true,
                                                pinned: false,
                                                resizable: false,
                                                width: width,
                                                height: height,
                                                content: url,

                                                deactivate: function() {
                                                    this.destroy(); 
                                                }
                                            }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
                                });
}
```

We've been struggling with this. No clear error shows up on Console window. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is nothing to do with this question, but it is not safer to provide direct link to your application even though it is a QA environment. Try to host the issue alone in some free sites and post it. It is better for you to avoid any future hacks. Be safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
.k-content-frame {
border: 0px none;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
}

div.k-window-content {
position: relative;
padding: 0.58em;
overflow: auto;
outline: 0px none;
height: 1000px;
}
```

> in kedndo.common.min.css find class and change change the height in pixel which is given in percentage which is difficult to determine by window it should be as above code.

Comment: The issue is not related to CSS because in IE and FireFox no traffic is even shown in the Network tab. Ajax fails beforehand..